# How to update data after fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm fetching data on `componentDidMount` in `fetchData` method. After that I'm trying to delete data with the method. I was trying to update date immediately in `deleteUser` method, but it doesn't work. How can I update this data after fetch with delete method?

```
fetchData = () => {
    let url = `https://contact-browser.herokuapp.com/contacts`;
    fetch(url, {method: 'get'}).then(resp => resp.json()).then((data) =>
        this.setState({
            data: Object.entries(data).map(([key,value])=>({key:Number(key),value}))
        })
    );
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

deleteUser = (id) => {
    let url = `https://contact-browser.herokuapp.com/contact/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {method: 'delete'}).then(resp => console.log(resp));
    this.fetchData();
};
```

Comment: When you say 'it didn't work', what does happens as opposed to what would you like to happen?

Comment: It deletes user, but data is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refetch your data after the delete fetch has fulfilled, this ensures that the data is fetched after the delete has fully resolved on the server.

```
deleteUser = (id) => {
    let url = `https://contact-browser.herokuapp.com/contact/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {method: 'delete'}).then(resp => {
         this.fetchData();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It "did not work" because of the async behaviour of JS. 
To be simple, when there is any waits in the code (like DB Call, API Call, etc), the JS code lets that particular to run and starts executing the next line. [More on this - https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/synchronous-asynchronous-javascript/](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/synchronous-asynchronous-javascript/)

In this case, since fetch is an i/o wait, the control moves to the next line - `this.fetchData()`. So, the `fetchData()` is called before delete may actually happens.

Following is another solution using async and await. [More to read](https://javascript.info/async-await)

```
deleteUser = async (id) => {
     let url = `https://contact-browser.herokuapp.com/contact/${id}`;
     let resp = await fetch(url, {method: 'delete'});
     console.log(resp);
     this.fetchData();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async and await

```
  deleteUser = async (id) => {
         let url = `https://contact-browser.herokuapp.com/contact/${id}`;
        const deleted = await fetch(url, {method: 'delete'}).then(resp => console.log(resp));
        if(deleted){
             await this.fetchData();
        }
   };
```